# Python/Django iterating over one list, while checking inside Object

Tags: python, django

What would the cleanest way to the following pseudocode be?

```
class Player
   id
   name

class Participant  (is a subset of Player with an added status)
   player_id (ForeignKey to Player)
   status
```

So you can have a list of Players (Wayne, Chuck, Bobby)
And then a list of Participants  (Wayne(status:YES), Bobby(status:NO))
Notice that Chuck is not inside the participant list.

So, I am iterating over all the Players, and outputting the status if the Participants exist.

```
player_list = list with Player objects
participant_list = list with Participant objects

for player in player_list:
   if player.id exists in participant_list //QUESTION IS HERE: HOW DO I DO THIS???
         print participant.status
```

I am not sure how to check the inside id of the list that contains Objects???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add in another loop

```
player_list = list with Player objects
participant_list = list with Participant objects

for player in player_list:
    for participant in participant_list:
        if player == participant.player:
            print participant.status
            break
```

Not the prettiest solution but simple.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the [`values_list()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method for `QuerySet` objects.

```
player_list = Player.objects.filter(...)
participant_list = Participant.objects.filter(...)
participant_player_id_list = participant_list.values_list('player_id', flat=True)

for player in player_list:
    if player.id in participant_player_id_list:
        print participant_list.get(player_id=player.id).status
```

Comment: The participant list will be iterated once for every player, and an SQL query will be run once for every player/participant. This means, if you have 100 players, you will iterate through the participant list 100 times and run up to 102 SQL queries. Convert the participant list into a dict and you will always have 1 iteration and 2 SQL queries, regardless of the number of players.

Answer (score 2):

For smaller sets of players/participants, a lookup dict is enough:

```
player_list = Player.objects.all()

# Get all relevant participants (or just all if you like)
player_ids = player_list.value_list('id', flat=True)
participant_list = Participant.objects.filter(player_id__in=player_ids)

# Create a lookup dict
participants = dict([(p.player_id, p) for p in participant_list])

# Everything is now prepared for quick access
for player in player_list:
    if player.id in participants:
        print participants[player.id].status
```

If you have to do this often, you might want to use a different approach. Here are three alternatives.

**Inheritance**

Use inheritance and to store the status in the database. This would make similar queries in the future much easier/more efficient:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_participant = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Participant(Player):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.is_participant = True
        super(Participant, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Having your data structured like this means that `Participant` objects always have the same fields as `Player` objects and that you can check if a player is a participant without hitting the database or looping through all the participants. Fetching the relevant participant however will incur a hit. A variation on this approach would be to attach a generic foreign key to the `Player`. Checking the attribute for `None` will tell you if the player is a participant too, and following the link will take you to the relevant database object.

**Denormalisation**

If status is the only value you need, you can store it on the player model too, and automatically synchronise it with your `Participant` value. if you use inheritance as above, you'll get it for free:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    participant_status = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Participant(Player):
    pass
```

You can query it like this:

```
for player in Player.objects.all()
    if player.participant_status:
         print participant.status
```

One drawback is that you will have to hide the status field from player forms. But the benefit is that you will be able to query a) if the player is a participant and b) get the status without hitting the database.

But this design is certainly not as clean as a normalised database, and it should only really be done if the cost is too great.

**One to one relation**

A final approach is to use the `OneToOneField` if this is a one to one relation. Theoretically you can link the two models from either side, but I'm not sure how this works with `select_related()`, which is what you'll want to use to avoid hitting the database more than once on lists.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    participant = models.OneToOneField('Participant', null=True)

class Participant(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

You query it like this:

```
player_list = Player.objects.all().select_related('participant')

for player in player_list:
   if player.participant_id is not None:
     print player.participant.status
```

Comment: Your answer was super indepth, but I don't think it answered the actual question, which was how to go about doing it with lists of objects, not querysets. He'd have to go about changing the way he's doing things, which in my opinion, would be a good thing to do. Querysets are way easier to work with than lists of objects.

Comment: The first approach (lookup dict) will work with lists too, just skip the lines that define the `person_list` and `participant_list` labels.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as the answers by James and John2x, you could roll three interesting python/django features together to do this in a way that is more explicit and probably much faster. The manager methods [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) and [in_bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.in_bulk) can be used to build a dictionary of model objects where each object's id attribute is mapped to the full object. The third trick is a feature of python dictionaries, which can be passed directly to the built-in function [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) to produce a set from the dictionary's keys. Like so:

```
import operator

# Get a bulk dict of player objects.
pl_objs = Player.objects
bulk_players = pl_objs.in_bulk(pl_obj.values_list("id", flat=True))

# Get a bulk dict mapping player.id to Participant instances.
bulk_participants = dict((operator.attrgetter("player_id"), x) 
                          for x in Participant.objects.all())

# Now find the overlap with a set intersection; print status.
for _id in set(bulk_players) & set(bulk_participants):
    print bulk_participants[_id].status
```

Answer (score -1):

or i think you can also do:

```
player_list = list with Player objects
participant_list = list with Participant objects

for player, participant in zip(player_list, participant_list):
    if player == participant.player:
            print participant.status
            break
```

but both `player_list` and `participant_list` have to have the same length

Comment: This won't do what the OP wants. It will compare player1 with participant1, player2 with participant2 and so on. The OP wants to compare each player with each participant (i.e., player1 with participants 1, 2 and 3, and then player2 with participants 1, 2 and 3). Plus the way the question is stated, the lists are quite likely to have different lengths.